# Notation for the set of all tuples whose elements are all part of a particular set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, notation

So, for example, let's say we have A = {3,6,1}
I would like to generate a set B which is such that the elements of B are tuples. Each tuple is such that if x is an element of the tuple then x is an element of A. Additionally, there are no repeated elements in any given tuple (each element of a given tuple is distinct).
If A contains x number of elements, then B should contain all the tuples (meeting the distinctness restriction) with 1 element, all the tuples with 2 elements, ...., all the tuples with x elements.

So in our example, B would be:
B = { (3) , (6) , (1) , (3,6) , (3,1) , (6,3) , (6,1) , (1,6), (1,3) , (3,6,1) , (3,1,6) , (6,3,1) , (6,1,3) , (1,3,6) , (1,6,3) }

so basically if A has x amount of elements, B is like the set of all permutations of A, taken x elements at a time, taken x-1 elements at a time, taken x-2 elements at a time,..., taken 1 element at a time. ....but instead of basic sets we have tuples.

Now, furthermore, I would like to have another set, C, which is such that x is an element of C iff x is an element of B, and x is such that its first element is less than its second (if there is a second), its second element is less than its third (if there is a third), etc...

(with "less than" being the standard less than relation among integers)

So we would get:
C = { (3) , (6) , (1) , (3,6) , (1,6) , (1,3) , (1,3,6) }

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interpreting the $n$-tuples with no repeated entries as injective functions from $[n]=\{0,1,2,\dots,n-1\}$ to $A$, and adopting the notation that $Y^{\underline{X}}$ is the set of all [injective functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function) from $X$ to $Y$, then you could notate it as:

$B = \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty A^{\underline{[n]}}$

As for denoting $C$, I think you would have an easier time referring instead to the [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of $A$ (*without the emptyset*) and reinterpret each set appearing as a tuple with entries in ascending order.

$C\simeq \mathcal{P}(A)\setminus\{\emptyset\}$

In terms of counting how large each set is, $|B|=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty |A|^{\underline{n}}$ using [falling factorial notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials) and $|C|=2^{|A|}-1$ (*if you removed the emptyset*)

Comment: I was in the middle of writing an answer with an identical suggestion, which leads me to think the notation is not so unnatural after all :) The notation $A^{\underline{[n]}}$ is by analogy with the falling factorial ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials)). (And I've also seen the notation $\binom{A}{k}$ to mean "the set of all $k$-element subsets of $A$".)

Comment: In regards to B, it is ok that we have the union going to infinity, as opposed to having |n| above the union sign (where |n| = size of [n])? n doesn't really go to infinity if the size of [n] = 3, no?

Comment: @Boolean_functions it is fine since there exist no injections from a set $X$ to a set $Y$ if $|X|>|Y|$.  Of course, you could stop at $|A|$ instead of continuing past.  Once we have passed $|A|$ then we are continually unioning the emptyset which has no further effect on the outcome.  $\bigcup\limits_{ n=1}^\infty A^{\underline{[ n]}} = \bigcup\limits_{n =1}^{|A|} A^{\underline{[n]}}$

Comment: Also just to help clarify for myself...B is the union of all  sets whose elements are also sets (they are sets of all particular injective functions...and functions are defined as sets). And so the elements of our union B, will be all these particular injective functions (sets)?   ...So now, if you _had to_ define C in terms of B (i.e., define C as being such that x is an element of C if x is an element of B and x meets the less than requirement), how would you do so? Since the elements of B _are sets_ and not tuples and since {2,3,5} is the same set as {3,5,2}...how would we be able to get

Comment: to get the tuples? That is, how would we be able to say something like "...also, each x in B must meet the requirement that the elements (of the tuples which don't exist in B) are ordered via less than relation...in order for x to be in C."  And also thanks for your last response, that clears that up.

Comment: Since {2,3,5} would _not_ be metting the "less than requirement" since {2,3,5} = {3,5,2} and that's not what we want. Again, thanks

Comment: @Boolean_functions why would you want to define $C$ from $B$ instead of directly from $A$?  Before we continue the discussion further, you need to keep in mind how tuples are defined.  One definition is that it is an $n$-tuple is an element of the cartesian product $\underbrace{A\times A\times \dots \times A}_{n~\text{times}}$.  A different yet equivalent definition however is that it is an injective function from $[n]$ to $A$ where $f(k-1)$ corresponds to the $k$'th entry in the tuple.

Comment: Well at first I didn't realize I could define C that easily from B...and now I'm just curious because I like notational matters

Comment: @Boolean_functions Although functions are technically sets, here there is absolutely no confusion since the $3$-tuple $(2,3,5)$ can be canonically expressed as the function $f(k)$ from $[3]$ to $A$ where $f(0)=2, f(1)=3, f(2)=5$.  This is different than the $3$-tuple $(3,5,2)$ which is instead the function $g(k)$ where $g(0)=3, g(1)=5, g(2)=2$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44221/discussion-between-boolean-functions-and-jmoravitz).